# Shortcut to property items

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013, vb6, keyboard-shortcuts

Background: I have extensionally used VB6 and loved a shortcut that it had.  When on any object in design view (i.e. form, text box, label), you could type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> + *property-first-letter* and VB6 would open up that property item in the property window and allow you to update the value. For example, if on a form, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> would pop down to the "Name" property, pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>N</kbd> again would pop to the next "N..." property "Negotiate Menus" and so forth.  This worked for any letter (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> would go to the captions property).  This was an great feature and saved scrolling and hunting with the mouse through all the property items.  I am back doing some VB.NET 2013 work and it drives me nuts that it does not have this feature.  I hate scrolling through the menu to find a property.

Question: Does anyone know if this feature can be 1) turned on, or 2) if there is a substitute way to quickly pop over to a property to change its value in VS 2013?  Searching and scrolling and clicking is driving me nuts.  Thanks.

Comment: So typing a letter after the dot is not quick enough?

Comment: @OneFineDay The auto fill after the "." on a property name when typing code is not what I am talking about.  I am talking about is:  In **design** view when an element is highlighted, such as a form, a text box, a label and you need to change the property value (or view a property value) in **design** view in the property window.  In vb6 you can quicky go to the property in the property window by type CTRL-SHIFT-<letter>.  In VB.NET you have to scroll through the properties.

Comment: I've used VB6 for years and had no idea this was a thing. From my exhaustive research (5 minutes of playing around), I don't think this is possible in VS2013.

Comment: @C-Pound Yes, this is a great feature in VB6.   Add a text box to a form,  CTRL-SHIFT-N type the name, CTRL-SHIFT-T type a default text string.  Add a label, CTRL-SHIFT-N change it's name then CTRL-SHIFT-C change it's caption.  Very fast to put controls on a form and set them up.

Comment: And yet, I've survived ~20 years without it. :D

Comment: This would be an interesting project for an addin.  I used it all the time too!

Comment: @BobRodes Yes, I agree!  I looked a little into doing that.  But I think the problem is that it would need to be attached to a CTRL-SHIFT-<letter>.  So I think there would need to be 26 key bindings?  Is there a way to just see the CTRL-SHIFT and then get the letter.   This needs more investigation.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Sure, not difficult.  Don't use key bindings, use the KeyPress event.  You can evaluate the Control.ModifierKeys property and AND it with Keys.Shift and Keys.Control to find out if those keys are down, check e.KeyChar, and away you go.  If you google KeyPress event, KeyPressEventArgs, and ModifierKeys you'll find all the code.

Comment: p. s. if ModifierKeys works the same way as the KeyPress event's Shift argument in VB6, it uses a set of three bits translated to decimal to determine what keys are pressed.  In VB6, the Shift argument was any number 0 through 7.  Leftmost bit was alt, next ctrl, next shift.  So 111, or 7, means all three are pressed.  Ctrl-Shift would be 3, or 011.